# PHP: ssh_2 connection not working for IIS server (Windows)

Tags: php, windows, iis, ssh

I am very new to PHP and struggling with ssh connections. I want to establish a ssh connection (IIS server), i tried all the steps suggested in previous posts but it didnt worked. I am using 64 bit windows machine. The steps which I have followed are:

(1.) Downloaded SSH2 PECL extension from link: https://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2/0.12/windows

(2.) copied php_ssh2.dll and php_ssh2.pdb to php/ext folder (php version 5.6)

(3.) copied libssh2.dll file in PHP folder and in Windows->SysWOW64

(4.) added "extention:php_ssh2.dll" in php.ini file.

(5.) Restarted the IIS server.
Now on running the following php code:

```
<?php
$connection = ssh2_connect('example.com', 22);

if (ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'User', 'Password')) {
echo "Authentication Successful!\n";
} else {
die('Authentication Failed...');
}
?>
```

I am getting error that "Call to undefined function ssh2_connect() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\testssh.php on line 5" 
Please help what is the thing I am missing or doing wrong. Are there any other files to include. Also PHP version which I am using is 5.6 and all the ssh files were for versions till 5.5, will that can create problem?

Comment: I've tried myself to make php_ssh2 work under PHP 5.6, but I didn't suceed. I couldn't find any binaries for PHP 5.6 either, so either you need to compile your own binaries or downgrade PHP to 5.5.

Comment: Thank you for help, finally i downgraded to PHP 5.5 only, now its working